# How can i make a confirm question using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, confirm

this is my button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Deletar", "Deletar", new { id = item.ID })
```

I tried to make a confirm question with Ajax like this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
            "AjaxAction",
            new AjaxOptions {OnBegin ="Deletar",Confirm="Você realmente deseja isso?" }))
           { @Html.ActionLink("Deletar", "Deletar",  new { id = item.ID },new { id = "Deletar" }) }
```

it does not work? what can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With standard link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Deletar", 
    "Deletar", 
    new { id = item.ID }, 
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Você realmente deseja isso?');" }
)
```

or if you want to use an AJAX link:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Deletar", 
    "Deletar", 
    new { id = "item.ID" },
    new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "Deletar", Confirm = "Você realmente deseja isso?" }
)
```

or an AJAX form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxAction", new { id = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "Deletar", Confirm = "Você realmente deseja isso?" }))
{ 
    <input type="submit" value="Deletar" />
}
```