# Ajax.ActionLink HtmlAttribute `onclick = "return confirm(...` Failing to Cancel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, razorengine

There are a tonne of questions pertaining to `AjaxActionLink` and the overloads. I have been unable to find a question which resolves my problem.

I have the following CSHTML in my Razor view

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Clear Failed Entires",
        "ClearFailedInviteEntries",
        "Tools",
         null,
         new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET" },
         new
         {
            onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to clear the failed invite entries?');",
            @class = "btn btn-lg btn-warning",
            role = "button"
         })
```

This fires the correct dialog with Okay and Cancel. However, when I press cancel the `ClearFailedInviteEntries` method still fires. I have attempted to put a check in this method

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ClearFailedInviteEntries(string s)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return null;
    ...
}
```

But `ModelState.IsValid` is always true and this is consistent across browsers. I have heard that using `return confirm` can cause different behaviors so i have attempted to use `onclick = "confirm(...` instead with no change.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit A. This is not an issue of the dialog **not** popping up. The dialog shows, but the selection in that dialog is not handled correctly.*

*Edit B. I have change the call to*

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Clear Failed Entires",
        "ClearFailedInviteEntries",
        "Tools",
         null,
         new AjaxOptions 
         { 
            HttpMethod = "GET",  
            Confirm = "Are you sure you want to clear the failed invite entries?"
         },
         new
         {
            @class = "btn btn-lg btn-warning",
            role = "button"
         })
```

*this works but now I get an odd check box on the dialog. How can i prevent/remove this?*

[image: Dialog]

Ps. This is in FireFox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AjaxOptions.confirm does not pop up in ActionLink or BeginForm Submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253487/ajaxoptions-confirm-does-not-pop-up-in-actionlink-or-beginform-submit)

Comment: You need to handle the `Confirm` ajax option - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261685/how-can-i-make-a-confirm-question-using-ajax) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke why does this not work with the `HtmlAttribute`? It shows the dialog, and i was of the understanding that if `cancel` was pressed the request should not be submitted?

Comment: @Backs It is not a duplicate of that. My dialog _does_ pop-up, but the selection in the dialog is not honored.

Comment: I suspect because its too late (the ajax call has already been made)

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. I should be able to keep the `HtmlAttributes` that identify the button but just move the dialog handle to the `AjaxAttribute` property. Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank worked but i am now getting a wierd check box on the dialog, any idea on this one, I have updated the question with an image?

Comment: You get a similar dialog in chrome if you call `confirm() or `alert()` multiple time - are you clicking on the link more than once (or creating other alerts or confirms in code?)

Comment: I was, if you want to make your comment and answer I will gladly accept, or I will delete the question.